# Ideal class group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, nt.number-theory

Hi everybody,

I wonder if someone could provide me with a simple example of a Dedekind ring whose ideal class group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

The point is I would like the example simple enough to be understood by a 4^th year student, with basic knowledge in algebra.

I know that every abelian group is the ideal class group of some Dedekind ring. It is proved in a paper of Claborn. I've read through the paper, and followed the proof, but it seems very intricate and needs lots of prerequisites (it needs stuff on Krull domains, valuation rings, plus other intermediate results)

In fact, any example of a Dedekind ring with an infinite ideal class group would do. I've seen in an other topic that the integral closure of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ in $\mathbb{C}(X)(\sqrt{X^3-X})$ would do, but the proof needs some non trivial results on elliptic curves.

I really would like the example and the computation of the ideal class group  as self-contained as it is possible. Maybe I'm asking too much, I don't know.

Thanks in advance !

Greg

Comment: Claborn's proof can be found here: ttp://www.math.uga.edu/~pete/claborn66.pdf Have you tried to work it out in the special case $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Specifically, let $J = \{j\}$ and $G = \mathbb{Z}$ in Proposition 6 and see what happens.

Comment: As I said in my message, yes I did. But it needs too many prerequisites on Krull domains, minimal primes and so on...



Comment: The example you mention can not have class group $\mathbb{Z}$. In fact, for any finitely generated algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, which is a Dedekind domain, the class group is divisible and hence can not be the integers. If you want to work with affine algebras over algebraically closed fields, you have to get out of Dedekind rings. Why not the easy universal one $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]/(xy-zw)$?

Comment: @GreginGre: Yes, but perhaps you can write down the ring explicitly (sure you can) in this special case and then start your own more elementary proof on it (if possible).

Comment: Well, I never said that it had ideal class group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. In the last part of my message, I was saying that any Dedekind ring with infinite class group would do. In fact, for the example I give,  the class group is isomorphic to the group of rational points of the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-x$.

And I really want a Dedekind ring, not a Krull domain.

Comment: @ Martin : well, I suppose I could try... The Krull domain with class group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ to start with is precisely $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]/(xy-zw)$, but I am afraid that it would need loads of ugly localizations to obtain a Dedekind domain. I'll try anyway.

But if I could obtain an example with an infinite class group (not necessarily $\mathbb{Z}$) in the spirit of "integral closure in something not too ugly", I would be happy !

Comment: Why don't you use an ell. curve over Q (not over C) whose group of rational points is isom. to Z? There are plenty of examples of that.

Comment: Let $C$ be a curve over number field $k$, such that $C(k)\not=\emptyset$ and such that 
${\rm Jac}(C)(k)$ is infinite. Let $P\in C(k)$. Let $U:=C\backslash\{P\}$. Then 
${\rm Pic}(U)={\rm Pic}(C)/[{\cal O}(P)]$, where $[{\cal O}(P)]$ is the subgroup generated by the 
line bundle ${\cal O}(P)$. Hence ${\rm Pic}(U)$ is infinite, because ${\rm Pic}(C)$ is an extension of 
${\rm Jac}(C)(k)$ by $\bf Z$ and hence ${\rm Pic}(C)/[{\cal O}(P)]$ cannot be zero. 
On the other hand $U$ is affine (because ${\cal O}(P)$ is ample) so you have an example of a Dedekind ring with infinite class group.

Comment: You can give an example of infinite class group without explicitly using algebraic geometry, if the students have seen elliptic functions (a.k.a. doubly periodic functions), as treated in Ahlfors's "Complex Analysis". 

Comment: Putting the three last remarks together, one gets the following example. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\bf Q$, such that 
$E({\bf Q})={\bf Z}$. Then $E\backslash\{0\}$ is affine and its class group is $\bf Z$. 

Comment: Ok, so for example ,  let $R=\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3-X+1)=\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. It is a Dedekind ring. The corresponding elliptic curve $E$ satisfies $E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}=0$, so the rational point $(1,1)$ has infinite order. Hence the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(x-1,y-1)$ should have infinite order in the ideal class group , right?

Is there any way to prove it by direct computations? 


Comment: Yes that's right. But I don't now how to prove this by direct computation. 